# How does EF Core access private backing fields?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, entity-framework-core

I have been using backing fields to better protect the value of some of the properties of my entities, as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field

Microsoft provides the following example, which is how I have implemented my backing fields:

```cs
public class Blog
{
    private string _validatedUrl;

    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    [BackingField(nameof(_validatedUrl))]
    public string Url
    {
        get { return _validatedUrl; }
    }
}
```

From the article:

> By default, EF will always read and write to the backing field

As I am happily using this convention, I started wonder: how can EF Core access the private backing field?

Comment: Private members are accessible via Reflection, so I'd assume that that's how EF does it.

Comment: could you explain to me what did you mean by private backing field ? you mean your private prop (_validatedUrl)? or what ?

Comment: Does it matter? A conclusive answer would have to show the exact EF code where this happens. Since it's not likely that people will delve into this code answers will have to speculate that it uses reflection. Therefore: opinion-based.

Comment: Accessibility (`private`, etc) is a lie, like `readonly` is a lie (at least without very specialized hardware). All data is accessible and mutable if you try hard enough. In Pirates of the Carribbean terms: they're more like guidelines than actual rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It almost certainly uses [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection). Here's an example of how that might work:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Blog));
var field = typeof(Blog).GetField(
    "_validatedUrl",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
field.SetValue(instance, "http://example.com/");
```

The `instance` object's `_validatedUrl` field now has the value `"http://example.com/"`.

Comment: For performance reason, the reflection is probably optimized via IL emit - so it might be *semantically* similar to this, while looking completely different in terms of the actual code.

Comment: and also, i think it is a good example to understanding
[**link**](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2014/september/access-auto-property-backing-field-with-reflection/)